# Storing value and checking if the value is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, if-statement

Is there a way I can check if the value of

```
<?php the_field('max_working_height')?>
```

is empty or store the value that will be displayed when I use  acnd check if that is empty or not. If the value is not empty then I have to make it execute a set of html code and php code like this

```
    <tr style="height: 25px; margin-left: 10px;">
<td style="margin-left: 10px;"><b>Max
  <?php the_field('max._outreach'); ?></td> 
</tr>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as it appears, you are using the ACF plugin, then `the_field()` echos out the value of the field. If you want to capture the value of the field, use `get_field()`.  Check out the docs [here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$maxWorkingHeight = the_field('max_working_height');

if (false == $maxWorkingHeight) {
    // print your html/php
} else {
    // you can print $maxWorkingHeight here if you need it
}
```

That assumes that your function returns a falsy value if the field isn't set (`null`, `false`, `0`, or an empty string are all examples of falsy values in PHP).